# grep string from file in R

Tags: r

When I use the command below to grep my target string `px`

```
x <- grep('px', readLines("file.txt"))

[]an$px  

[1] 2 12  # x returns 2 and 12th line
```

But when I want to grep the string as `[1]$px`

```
x <- grep('[1]$px', readLines("file.txt"))
```

`x` returns `integer(0)`

My question is, how can I get `2` and `12` as well rather than `integer(0)` if my targeted string is `[1]$px`?

Comment: Please cut and paste the text of your file (or part of it) rather than posting an image link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brackets carry special meaning in regular expressions.  Add `fixed=TRUE` to your parameters in grep tells it to interpret the pattern as is.  The other option is to escape the brackets but if you don't need the full power of regular expressions and just want to search for a specific string then using `fixed=TRUE` is the better option anyways.

```
x <- grep('[[1]]$px', readLines("file.txt"), fixed = TRUE)
```